# xsl template match ignore namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've read a lot of examples about ignore namespaces but can't seem to bring this concept to fruition inside template match.

Here's my sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Response xmlns:ResB="http://www.aaa.com/v1" xmlns:dpconf="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" xmlns:exsl="http://xmlns.opentechnology.org/xslt-extensions/common" xmlns="http://www.aaa.com/v2">
         <Status>
            <Code>00000</Code>
        </Status>
      </Response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I can't have the namespace in the ouptut. Here's an example of the desired output:

```
<A>
   <Transformed>0000</Transformed>
</A>
```

This isn't outputting my nodes, so how can I have an xslt to match the Response node and work off of that?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'Response']">
<A>
<Transformed><xsl:value-of select="Status/Code"/></Transformed>
</A>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why would you want to ignore the namespace? Just declare it and use it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:v2="http://www.aaa.com/v2"
  exclude-result-prefixes="v2"
>
  <xsl:template match="v2:Response">
    <A>
      <Transformed>
        <xsl:value-of select="v2:Status/v2:Code" />
      </Transformed>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually - when I use that, the <A> node then has the namespace attached to it and that messes up the format I need to have. Suggestions?

Comment: Oh - I found I can use 
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="v2"

Comment: THANKS a lot !!...  XML namespaces makes sense now.